# Observer Pattern and Circular References

Tags: observer-pattern

I was checking this example of Observer Pattern.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm

It seems that there is a circular reference when Observer Pattern is used.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Subject {

   private List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();
   private int state;

   public int getState() {
      return state;
   }

   public void setState(int state) {
      this.state = state;
      notifyAllObservers();
   }

   public void attach(Observer observer){
      observers.add(observer);      
   }

   public void notifyAllObservers(){
      for (Observer observer : observers) {
         observer.update();
      }
   }    
}


public class BinaryObserver extends Observer{

  public BinaryObserver(Subject subject){
      this.subject = subject;
      this.subject.attach(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void update() {
      System.out.println( "Binary String: " + Integer.toBinaryString( subject.getState() ) ); 
   }
}
```

I am not posting all the other code, but from the initial look it seems that such design will almost always have a circular reference. Am I misunderstanding anything here?

Thanks,

Comment: Where do you see a circular reference?

Comment: Subject depends on Observer and BinaryObserver depends on Subject.  However that's not circular.  Subject would have to depend on BinaryObserver first.

Comment: Are you worried that GCs can't collect cycles? They can.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are right. Both objects know each other if that is what your are referring to. The important thing is *what* they know about each other. While the `BinaryObserver` knows the `Subject` in detail the `Subject` knows only `Observers`. To be more precise the `Subject` doesn't know the details about your `BinaryObserver` it can only send messages to it that are defined in the `Observer` class. In that way `Subject` is decoupled from the details of your `BinaryObserver`class.

To sum up, while the coupling of the `BinaryObserver` to the `Subject` is very high the coupling in the opposite direction is weak.

Comment: I have seen some designs e.g. GSON api where GSON building fails if there are circular references (I think the exception is StackOverflowException) - but surely, this doesn't mean the Observer Pattern is wrong and cannot use utilities such as GSON?

Comment: @hagubear This is because you cannot serialize an instance which has a reference to itself or through some chain of dependencies, itself, otherwise a tree representing said data would never end.  This is more of a technical issue related to serialization and not general best practice (though admittedly avoiding circular references is best practice anyway).

Comment: I hope I could read your answer early when I learning Observer Pattern...

Answer (score 2):

**Update: As JimmyJames pointed out in the comments, the question is about circular *references* and not about circular *dependencies***

---

**Original Answer, where I thought we were discussing circular *dependencies*:**

Actually, because of polymorphism, there is no circular dependency here. Let's look closer at the dependencies to see why:

- `BinaryObserver` depends on `Subject` and `Observer`
- `Subject` depends on `Observer`
- `Observer` doesn't have any dependencies.

---

By having the `Subject` depend on the `Observer` interface rather than any concrete implementation, [the Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) is being followed. This principle states:

1. High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions.
2. Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend on abstractions.

So, although it may look like circular dependency at a glance, it's really just polymorphing a concrete implementation that depends on `Subject` (`BinaryObserver`) to an interface with no `Subject` dependency (`Observer`), and injecting that polymorphed object into `Subject`'s constructor. Thus, no circular dependency.

Comment: The BinaryObserver instance has a reference to the Subject instance.  The Subject instance has a reference to the BinaryObserver instance via a list -> circular dependency.

Comment: A Circular Dependency isn't about references to instances on runtime, it's about classes (or modules) depending on each other in order to function. Subject does not require BinaryOperator to function.

Comment: OK, fair point on terminology but the question is about circular *references* not *dependencies*.  It doesn't appear to have been edited.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Thanks for pointing out, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the circular reference with a slight change to the Observer interface:

```java
interface Observer {
  void update(Subject subject);
}
```

The notifyAll becomes:

```java
public void notifyAllObservers(){
  for (Observer observer : observers) {
     observer.update(this);
  }
}
```

There are potentially some tradeoffs, but in the example you have shown, you would only need a single Observer object for all the Subjects in the application.  If you do it as the tutorial shows, you need one for every Subject.  That's a lot of extra objects hanging around just to keep track of a reference which is easily passed in.

Another issue with the Observable pattern is that you can end up with memory leaks because the observed object is holding references to the observers.  Usually the pattern includes a remove method but consider using `WeakReference` to allow objects to automatically stop listening when they fall out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple answer

It's not a cyclic problem; it's a different type of coupling issue because `BinaryObserver` is a concrete class.

## Detailed answer

*The answer below is taken from the book Java Application Architecture by Kirk Knoernschild*.

### Break cycle at the class level

[image]

> It's not a cyclic problem; it's a different type of coupling issue `BinaryObserver` is a concrete class. (page 52)

### Break cycle at the module level

[image]

To have an acyclic dependency between modules, we must move `Subject` and `Observer` in the same module. (page 54, figure 4.4 ans figure 4.5)

### Conclusion

- Observer design pattern has acyclic dependencies between classes
- Obersver design pattern has acyclic dependencies between modules

### The type of coupling

In the schema 1 and 2 we **interting the relation**, [dependency inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

> Interving  the relationships allows us to deploy `package2` module independent of the `package1` module. But I'd like to explore another option [...] the ability to **test** and **deploy** the `package2` module independently.

> I can test and deploy `package1` module independently. But if I want to test and deploy both modules independently [...] I need to completely eliminate the relationship altogether. (page 123 and figure 8.4)

[image]